# Only some classes in my CSS file are being read and used

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a theme for WordPress and trying to make some functionality changes, however, it seems like some CSS classes are not using the style outlined in my code while others are.

HTML & PHP Code

```
<div class="quantityContainer"><!-- Div Class 1, Not being read --><?php
        
        woocommerce_quantity_input(
            array(
                'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
            )
        );
        
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
        ?>
            
        
        <div class="flex-grow-1"> <!-- Div Class 2, Being read -->
            
            <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
        </div>  <!-- CUSTOM LINE -->
        </div> <!-- CUSTOM LINE -->
```

CSS Code:

```
.quantityContainer{
    display: flex !important;
}

.quantity{
    float: left;
}

.flex-grow-1{
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
```

The problem is that both the .quantity and .flex-grow-1 classes are being effected by the style but the .quantityContainer class isn't.

I've attached some images to show the Chrome Dev Tools code.

[Flex Grow Class with CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu6Ca.png)

[Quantity Class with CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVDmW.png)

[Quantity Container class without CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGVBz.png)

Page URL: https://toolsandmachinery.co.uk/product/scan-combiflex-330/

I've tried:

- Changing Class Names
- Changing from Class to ID Changing
- Changing CSS code location (to master style.css)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, but I'm not 100% certain, that your problem is with your attempt at a CSS comment:

```css
// Styling to make quantity field and button inline
.quantityContainer{
    display: flex !important;
}
```

CSS doesn't support this type of commenting, you must use `/* ... */` [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments) instead. I think for whatever reason this is invalidating the next line which is the one you say isn't being applied.

**Correct way:**

```css
/* Styling to make quantity field and button inline */
.quantityContainer{
    display: flex !important;
}
```